# A Theorem concerning Meromorphic Functions, complex analysis.

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there a theorem in complex analysis which says something along the lines that,

If two meromorphic function have same set of poles then they are same. I mean to say that, given a set of poles $M=\{z_1,z_2,\dots,z_n\}$, there is a unique meromorphic function having poles at $z_1,z_2,\dots,z_n$

If there is such theorem, I request you to mention books/online source where I can find the proof.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/906752/can-any-meromorphic-function-be-represented-as-a-product-of-zeroes-and-poles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is a meromorphic function and $g$ is an entire function without zeros, then $fg$ is a meromorphic function with exactly the same poles as $f$.

The relevant uniqueness theorem is the [Weierstrass factorization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem).

See also the [Mittag-Leffler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler%27s_theorem).

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly I was looking for!